# PHP newline not working in text file

Tags: php, file, text, newline

I am using the PHP code:

```
$numberNewline = $number . '\n';
fwrite($file, $numberNewline);
```

to write $number to a file.

For some reason \n appears in the file. I am on a mac. What might be the problem?

Comment: Not sure, but I think \n only works if you use " not ' (`'\n'` is wrong while `"\n"` is right)

Comment: Just off the bat, Mac, Windows and *nix use different linefeeds (in general). Why, God only knows. It has driven me nuts. Do a search for newline, and see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.

Comment: Oh yes, and you need to use double quoted strings.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$numberNewline = $number . "\n";
fwrite($file, $numberNewline);
```

Try this

Comment: For me this is not working even for new line.
The only thing is working for me is "\r\n" with text file

Comment: It depends on the operating system of the server.

Comment: okay. My development and production server both are different(OS is also differ), Can you please let me know which one should I use?

Comment: See chotesah's answer below

Answer (score 71):

`'\n'` in single quotes is a literal `\n`.
`"\n"` in double quotes is interpreted as a line break.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 36):

If inserting "\n" does not yield any results, you can also try "\r\n" which adds a "carriage-return" and "new line."

Answer (score 25):

Use **PHP_EOL**. PHP_EOL is platform-independent and good approach.

```
$numberNewline = $number .PHP_EOL;
fwrite($file, $numberNewline);
```

*PHP_EOL is cross-platform-compatible(DOS/Mac/Unix).*

Comment: For some reason I couldn't recall how to do this, and so I asked the Internet and landed here.  As soon as I saw this answered I remembered.  Duh.  This, really, is the best one.  The others work, perhaps, but this is the most correct answer.

Comment: is it? it will save raw emails incorrectly on unix for example, not that perfect

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not seeing a new line is because .txt files write its data like a stack. It starts writing from the beginning, then after it finishes, the blinking line (the one indicating where your next character is going to go) goes back to the beginning. So, your "\n" has to go in the beginning.

Instead of writing:

```
<?php
     $sampleLine = $variable . "\n";
     $fwrite($file, $sampleLine);
?>
```

You should write:

```
<?php
     $sampleLine = "\n" . $variable;
     $fwrite($file, $sampleLine);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> $numberNewline = $number . '\r\n';
>
> fwrite($file, $numberNewline);

Try This

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me but it was so simple - here is the code...
please use the KISS method.

```
echo file_put_contents("test.txt","\r\n \r\n$name \r\n$email \r\n$phone", FILE_APPEND);
```

It set a new blank line and then appends one line at a time.