# How to limit a number of characteres in txt using PHP

Tags: php, file, php-7

I would like a way to break the line when it gets to 360 characters in a txt file.

Example:

In my script my output

[image]
I'd like this output

[image]

My code to write in file

```
$string = $data.'*'."\n";

$fp = fopen( 'registro.txt', 'a+' );
if( !$fp ){
  echo 'Erro inesperado, não foi possivel abrir o arquivo';
  exit;
}else{
   fwrite( $fp, $stringSEFIP."\n");
}
```

Comment: Split your string by 360 characters, add `\n` to each element then join the array. Write that to your file.

Comment: Yes, I do that, but when I write in txt file the information not write line by line. I like in this form:  line 1: info 1 \n line 2: info 2, but in my script the data in the same line like this info1 info 2 info 3.

Comment: If you are already doing that why won't you show us that PHP code then? You may want to use `\r\n` depending on your OS.

Comment: $teste  = substr($string,0,360);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP newline not working in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858443/php-newline-not-working-in-text-file)

Comment: In linux the data were formatted in the right way, when I ran this script in windows the formatation broke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$string = $data.'*'."\n";

$skip = 360;

$fp = fopen( 'registro.txt', 'a+' );
if( !$fp ){
  echo 'Erro inesperado, não foi possivel abrir o arquivo';
  exit;
}else{
    $pos = 0;
    while ($pos < strlen($str)) {
        fwrite( $fp, substr($stringSEFIP, $pos, $skip) . PHP_EOL);
        $pos += $skip;
    }
}
```